# Insert mongodb to my json file

Tags: json, mongodb

```js
"Title": "Anti-Mage",
    "Url": "antimage",
    "ID": 1,
    "Lore": "The monks of Turstarkuri watched the rugged valleys below their mountain monastery as wave after wave of invaders swept through the lower kingdoms. Ascetic and pragmatic, in their remote monastic eyrie they remained aloof from mundane strife, wrapped in meditation that knew no gods or elements of magic. Then came the Legion of the Dead God, crusaders with a sinister mandate to replace all local worship with their Unliving Lord's poisonous nihilosophy. From a landscape that had known nothing but blood and battle for a thousand years, they tore the souls and bones of countless fallen legions and pitched them against Turstarkuri. The monastery stood scarcely a fortnight against the assault, and the few monks who bothered to surface from their meditations believed the invaders were but demonic visions sent to distract them from meditation. They died where they sat on their silken cushions. Only one youth survived - a pilgrim who had come as an acolyte, seeking wisdom, but had yet to be admitted to the monastery. He watched in horror as the monks to whom he had served tea and nettles were first slaughtered, then raised to join the ranks of the Dead God's priesthood. With nothing but a few of Turstarkuri's prized dogmatic scrolls, he crept away to the comparative safety of other lands, swearing to obliterate not only the Dead God's magic users - but to put an end to magic altogether. ",
    "SuggestedRoleLevels": {
      "Carry": 2,
      "Escape": 3
    },
    "Enabled": true,
    "Side": "Radiant",
    "Aliases": [
      "am"
    ],
    "AttackCapabilities": "DOTA_UNIT_CAP_MELEE_ATTACK",
    "PrimaryAttribute": "DOTA_ATTRIBUTE_AGILITY",
    "Initial": {
      "Strength": 22,
      "StrengthGain": 1.2,
      "Agility": 22,
      "AgilityGain": 2.8,
      "Intelligence": 15,
      "IntelligenceGain": 1.8,
      "Health": 568,
      "HealthRegen": 0.91,
      "Mana": 195,
      "ManaRegen": 0.61,
      "Armor": 2.08,
      "MagicResistance": 0.25,
      "MinDamage": 49,
      "MaxDamage": 53,
      "AvgDamage": 51,
      "IncreasedAttackSpeed": 22,
      "BaseAttackTime": 1.45,
      "AttackTime": 1.19,
      "AttacksPerSecond": 0.84,
      "AttackAnimationPoint": 0.3,
      "AttackAcquisitionRange": 600,
      "AttackRange": 128,
      "VisionDayRange": 1800,
      "VisionNightRange": 800,
      "ProjectileSpeed": 0,
      "MovementSpeed": 315,
      "TurnRate": 0.5
    },
    "Abilities": [
      {
        "Title": "Mana Break",
        "Url": "mana_break",
        "HeroAbilityUrl": "antimage_mana_break",
        "ID": 5003,
        "Description": "Burns an opponent's mana on each attack. Mana Break deals 60% of the mana burned as damage to the target. Mana Break is a Unique Attack Modifier, and does not stack with other Unique Attack Modifiers.",
        "Lore": "A modified technique of the Turstarkuri monks' peaceful ways is to turn magical energies on their owner.",
        "Notes": [
          "Mana Burn is blocked by spell immunity.",
          "You can lifeleech the damage dealt by this skill with a Lifesteal aura."
        ],
        "Type": "DOTA_ABILITY_TYPE_BASIC",
        "Behavior": [
          "DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE"
        ],
        "DamageType": "DAMAGE_TYPE_PHYSICAL",
        "AbilitySpecial": [
          {
            "Name": "Damage Per_burn",
            "Url": "damage_per_burn",
            "Value": [
              0.6
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "Mana Burned Per Hit",
            "Url": "mana_per_hit",
            "ValueType": "FIXED",
            "Value": [
              28,
              40,
              52,
              64
            ]
          }
        ]
```

That is a slice from my json file, I wanna insert it inside a mongodb called dota2.

I was trying the command:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray -d dota2 -c docs --file heroes.json
```

the return told me:

```
2015-10-31T12:09:35.755-0200    connected to: localhost
2015-10-31T12:09:35.842-0200    imported 110 documents
```

But I won't get my data information, the command : `db.dota.find()` 
Return empty...

Someone can help me? Yes...I am a newbie with mongodb. :/

Answer (score 0):

As per your command you are inserting the data into the collection named docs present in database dota2.

So you should probably do like

```
use dota2;
db.docs.find();
```

Comment: Shivanand, to use this in another application context like in angular routes to access, I always should access the collection?

Comment: Yes, should always access from collection. Use the database name when getting a connection object to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand, my data are inside mongodb! But inside docs collections :) It works!